# Double digit format in impex

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I created an impex similitar to this:

```
INSERT_UPDATE Unit;code[unique=true];type(code)[default='TEST', unique=true] ;conversion;
                  ; a                ;; 0,001
                  ; b                ;; 0,001
                  ; c                ;; 1
                  ; d                ;; 1
                  ; e                ;; 1000
```

It works just fine on my local. But in another test enviroment the comma is not working as a digit separator. What should I do to indicate in this impex that it should use comma as a digit separator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after I added to the impex header:

```
#% impex.setLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Like this:

```
#% impex.setLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
INSERT_UPDATE Unit;code[unique=true];type(code)[default='TEST', unique=true] ;conversion;
                  ; a                ;; 0,001
                  ; b                ;; 0,001
                  ; c                ;; 1
                  ; d                ;; 1
                  ; e                ;; 1000
```

Comment: You can either use `#% impex.setLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);` or `.` instead of `,`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input, but we use a dynamic logic to import the same impex for different sites with different headers, it's more than 50 sites. So either I would have to implement 50 impex to each one of them individually with . or , as a separator. Or force this one ti use a specific locale independent from the default locale value. 

So if I just changed to "." it would work for those who are failing, but it would stop working for those who are working.